# from the rails console, how can I query a mongo collection with human readable output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

from the rails console, how can I easily query a mongo collection with nice tab style output in a human readable form:

Person.all.each { |p| pp p }

that will return a mess of each document printed one after the other, but none of the cols are lined up.

Comment: thanks everyone, I added this method to criteria: https://github.com/altly/mongoid/commit/c056bf5d2b93f92539b75a3af69466c60d1806a5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you have a couple options:

1. Be content without columns and use pp or the very pretty [awesome_print](http://www.rubyinside.com/awesome_print-a-new-pretty-printer-for-your-ruby-objects-3208.html).  With awesome_print I often do: `ap Person.all.map(&:to_mongo)`  The `to_mongo` method will produce nicer output than pp'ing or ap'ing the object itself.
2. Roll your own.  Check out [terminal-table](https://github.com/visionmedia/terminal-table) as a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON, data is not displayed lined up because documents may not have the same number of "columns". There's **NO** schema, so each document can have a different number of "columns" and still be stored under the same collection, That's why each document is displayed on it's own without relationship to other documents.

If you want to display them in a particular way, you need to take the output and format it on your own application, it doesn't make sense for the console to assume all the documents have exactly the same "columns".

Comment: all of the mongo gui apps like "MongoVUE" do this.  You are correct, the data is json.  But 99% of the time it can be displayed like a traditional SQL result set.  I'm just looking for a Foo.all.to_table method for the console.

Answer (score 0):

I usually inspect mongo collections this way:
`ap Person.pluck(:id, :name, :dreams)`